# web2py form process

Tags: python, web2py

I've recently downloaded web2py and starting going through the examples in the provided book.  In the [postbacks part in the overview section of the book](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/3#Postbacks), there is an example that reads:

```
def first():
    form = FORM(INPUT(_name='visitor_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
              INPUT(_type='submit'))
    if form.process().accepted:
        session.visitor_name = form.vars.visitor_name
        redirect(URL('second'))
    return dict(form=form)
```

This bombs out with message:
 "('FORM' object has no attribute 'process')"

I have run a dir() against the form variable and it doesn't indicate that there is any such method as "process".  Has this been removed from web2py or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of web2py,

.process() is a new method included in recent updates.

Which version are you using?

You can use

```
if form.accepts(request, session):
    ....
```

Comment: hmmm possibly, I just got the latest available from the ubuntu (oneiric 11.10) pkg mgr.  web2py v1.97.1 is therefore installed and current web2py is 1.99.4 stable so guess that's it. Thanks... will have to install it from source I guess.

Comment: Right, that's sorted it thanks.  It's ridiculously easy to run it from source anyway!